# Problem with solution and project with same name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have restored a solution from my previous, trashed Vista laptop to my newly installed XP laptop, both VS 2008 SP1.  In a folder called `Rhino`, I have a solution called `Rhino.sln`, and a web site in a folder called `Rhino`.  When I open the solution, VS only opens the project.

Note that when I copied the root `Rhino` folder to my new machine, I received a complaint that 'the folder already contains an item called `Rhino`'.  I don't know what this indicates, but I just assumed another svn confusion somewhere, and recreated the solution, and copied the existing web site over and added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option in VS 2008, under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions: `Always show solution` that is off by default.  Been so long since I installed VS I still can't remember seeing it before.

Comment: Yep, projects never exist on their own in VS.  There's always a solution somewhere.